# Ùpdate API information regularly in python desktop widget

Tags: python, api, tkinter

I have been doing a beginner python desktop application with tkinter.
I am pulling information via API and want this information to be updated every 10 second. Sadly I could not make it work via threading and sleep function.
Any suggestions?

```
from tkinter import *
import urllib.request
import json
import threading
from tkinter import ttk
import time

def main():

    win = Tk()
    win.tk_setPalette(background='black', foreground='white')
    win.title('Crypto Desktop Ticker')
    win.geometry('250x35')

    #def getInfo():
    url1 = urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/")
    data1 = json.loads(url1.read())
    priceusd = data1[0]['price_usd']
    onehourchange = data1[0]['percent_change_1h']

    output1 = ("BTC "+priceusd+"USD ("+onehourchange+"%)"  )

    url2 = urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/cardano/?convert=USD") #as url:
    data2 = json.loads(url2.read())
    priceusd = data2[0]['price_usd']
    onehourchange = data2[0]['percent_change_1h']

    output2 = ("ADA "+priceusd+"USD ("+onehourchange+"%)"  )

    T = Text(win, height=2, width=100)
    T.pack()
    T.insert(END, output1 + '\n' +
         output2)
    T.config(state=DISABLED)
    win.mainloop()
    time.sleep(10)

main()
#threading.Timer(10.0, main().start)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that gets the data and updates the GUI. Have this method use `after` to schedule itself to run every 10 seconds.

```
def refresh():
    # get the information
    info = <your code to get the information>

    # update the display
    T.configure(state="normal")
    T.delete("1.0", "end")
    T.insert("end", info)
    T.configure(state="disabled")

    # call again in 10 seconds
    win.after(10000, refresh)
```